# Cancel click on parent when mousedown on child

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events

I've read several posts similar questions as this one, but none of them worked for me.

There are two divs, one is the parent of the other:

```
<parent>
  <son></son>
</parent>
```

- "Son" has event handlers for `mousedown`, `mousemove` and `mouseup`.
- "Parent" has an event handler for `click`.
- "Parent" is bigger than "son".

Requirements:

- One has to be able to mousedown-mousemove-mouseup inside "son". [OK]
- One has to be able to click "parent". [OK]

But, if somebody drags the mouse out of "son" and releases it, "parent"'s click handler fires.

Is there any way to avoid it?

Should I change my layout?

http://jsfiddle.net/g3qzkz74/17/

(Please, pure JavaScript!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent "son" `click` event from bubbling up DOM tree:

```
function sonClick(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}

document.getElementById('son').addEventListener('click', sonClick, false);
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g3qzkz74/14/

Comment: Hi, sorry, first, I moved the list of events to the top of page and it caused to lose focus on the elements. It's now fixed on http://jsfiddle.net/g3qzkz74/17/

The original problem remains with your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/g3qzkz74/18/ (updated with element placement).

Second, I'm trying to reproduce this on Google Chrome.

Thank you!